# NIC stays on after shutdown

Tags: networking

Network stays on at 1Gb after shutdown...with Windows 7 it would just shutdown with the rest.
Is there a way to make the NIC behave as in Windows 7, this is not the router's computer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Answer (score 1):

Disable Wake on Lan in the bios.  If you have WOL enabled, then the NIC stays on so it can wake up the computer.

Comment: Wake on LAN IS disabled. Installing Ubuntu 11.04 created this situation, on Windows 7 the NIC would shutdown. I never changed it in the BIOS and it is still off, but Ubuntu seems to keep it up. I'm sure its just a flag somewhere...but where...

Comment: You can configure WOL with `ethtool` but the default is normally set by the bios.  Windows usually ignores the bios setting and disables it unless you explicitly enable it in device manager.